# laravel-admin + laravel 5.5 save 2 field with same value

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-admin

I have a form that needs to generate `slug`, I use laravel-admin by z-song.

link: https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin/

In documentation, a form can simply like this:

```
protected function form()
{
    $form = new Form(new Post);

    $form->text('title');
    $form->hidden('slug');

    return $form;
}
```

buts it's both manual input. that's not what I need since slug needs to be auto-generated.

I am trying do like this:

```
protected function form()
{
    $form = new Form(new Post);

    $form->text('title', 'Title');
    $form->hidden('slug')->value(str_slug($form->title));

    return $form;
}
```

buts its result `NULL` for the slug one.

so how to make it happen?

Comment: I don't know how `laravel-admin` works, but it seems that in the creation of the form there is no `$form->title`, that's why you get `NULL`. If the slug needs to be created from the title, then don't add it to the form, just generate it when the model is being saved.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel admin has [some callbacks](https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/model-form-callback) on $form, that can be useful for generating slug case :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


$form->text('title');
$form->hidden('slug');


$form->saving(function (Form $form) {

    $form->slug = Str::slug($form->title);

});
```

Note : You can read more about Laravel Helpers, ex. [Str::slug](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-slug).